# Phonegap 3.5, Android wrong Icon in Config > Apps

Tags: android, cordova

I've a very strange problem. Hope you guys can help me with this.

**I use Phonegap 3.5**

```
<icon src="www/res/icon.png" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
```

After installing the app via "phonegap run android", i got all icons, except the one under "configuration > apps".

[image]

Any ideas?